# ajax call error 500 asmx

Tags: ajax, asmx

when i call a web services from ajax from development environment it works, but when i deploy it to production, i get error 500 from xmldoc.state.

The method i call from ajax is a test method:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool MailExist(string mail)
{
    return false;

}
```

if i call the asmx url directly it works and obiowsly return "false"

So i really don't know where is the problem.

Usally error 500 indicates a server problem but the server is up and return the value of the method if you call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: it was a f..g "S"

```
#if DEBUG
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://secure.domain.com/UiService/")]
#else
        [WebService(Namespace = "http**s**://secure.domain.com/UiService/")]
#endif
```